# In Cloud9 should my HTML and CSS3 files be within my Python project?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Admittedly - I have minimal knowledge of what's going on here. However all I want to do is get this environment up and running so I can start to mess around with developing a single page web app in the C9 IDE. Any help, literally any, will be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: A bit more info would be helpful here. What is the file structure you currently have? Are you using any frameworks to build your app?

Answer (score 0):

Html and CSS files also known as "static" files are usually kept in a folder called public or client. It differs from language to language and framework to framework and also depends on personal preference or team preference. There are no real right places for you to place your static files yet best practices can be found if you google python **folder structures**. As long as your files can see your other files when you point to them you're set.